# How can I choose specific size of integers without array that I want to pass it to the function

Tags: java, file-io

The Function --additem() have Integer as parameter but I do not want to pass all integers. I need to send it one then call other function.

```
public void readfile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {              
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
            // use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text
            // DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));            
            Scanner file2  = new Scanner(br);    

            while(file2.hasNext()){     
                String str = file2.nextLine();
                String[] spl= str.split(" ");               
                datas12.add(str);                       
                //System.out.println(str);          
                for(String line : spl) {                    
                    //System.out.println(datas12);                  
                    vs = Integer.parseInt(line);                
                    cb.addItem(vs); //Its adding all integers from vs.
                }                   
            }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to achieve? Because as for now it's totally unclear what you're asking...

Comment: You can't call a function as an argument. You can call another method from inside the method though.

Comment: you need to show where vs and cb are declared. More detail required

Comment: This is the other class which has the definition of function addItem(). I am trying to pass integer(vs) from previous class to addItem() function. I am able to pass all data from file into this function as integers but I want to add One line at a time.

CODE BELOW:::

public class Data{

 public List<Integer> datas1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
 
 
 
 public void addItem(Integer v) { 
 datas1.add(v);
 System.out.println(datas1+"Testing");

}

Comment: This is the simple version-by hardcoding the input. I am thinking to do the same thing by using the File input(as decribed above) instead of hard coding it.    CODE BELOW:::::             Data trans = new Data();
  trans.addItem(1);
  trans.addItem(2);
  trans.addItem(3);
  algo.process(trans);

Comment: I am able to solve this issue.thank you all